# R Precision for Double - Why code returns negative why positive outcome expected?

Tags: r, double, precision

I am testing 2 ways of calculating Prod(b-a), where a and b are vectors of length n. Prod(b-a)=(b1-a1)*(b2-a2)*(b3-a3)*... (bn-an), where b_i>a_i>0 for all i=1,2,3, n.  For some special cases, another way (Method 2) of calculation this prod(b-a) is more efficient. It uses the following formula, which is to expand the terms and sum them:

[image]

Here is my question is: When it happens that a_i very close to b_i, the true outcome could be very, very close 0, something like 10^(-16). Method 1 (substract and Multiply) always returns positive output. Method 2 of using the formula some times return negative output ( about 7~8% of time returning negative for my experiment).  Mathematically, these 2 methods should return exactly the same output. But in computer language, it apparently produces different outputs.

Here are my codes to run the test. When I run the testing code for 10000 times, about 7~8% of my runs for method 2 returns negative output. According to the official document, the R double has the precision of "2.225074e-308" as indicated by R parameter: ".Machine$double.xmin".  Why it's getting into the negative values when the differences are between 10^(-16) ~ 10^(-18)? Any help  that sheds light on this will be apprecaited. I would also love some suggestions concerning how to practically increase the precision to higher level as indicated by R document.

```r
##########  Testing code 1.  
ftest1case<-function(a,b)  {
  n<-length(a)
  if (length(b)!=n) stop("---------  length a and b are not right.")
  if ( any(b<a) ) stop("----------  b has to be greater than a all the time.")
  out1<-prod(b-a)
  
  out2<-0
  N<-2^n
  for ( i in 1:N ) {
    tidx<-rev(as.integer(intToBits(x=i-1))[1:n])
    tsign<-ifelse( (sum(tidx)%%2)==0,1.0,-1.0)
    out2<-out2+tsign*prod(b[tidx==0])*prod(a[tidx==1])
  }
  c(out1,out2)
}


##########  Testing code 2.  
ftestManyCases<-function(N,printFreq=1000,smallNum=10^(-20))
{
  tt<-matrix(0,nrow=N,ncol=2)
  n<-12
  for ( i in 1:N) {
    a<-runif(n,0,1)
    b<-a+runif(n,0,1)*0.1
    tt[i,]<-ftest1case(a=a,b=b)
  
    if ( (i%%printFreq)==0 ) cat("----- i = ",i,"\n")
    if ( tt[i,2]< smallNum ) cat("------ i = ",i, " ---- Negative summation found.\n")
  }
  
  tout<-apply(tt,2,FUN=function(x)  { round(sum(x<smallNum)/N,6) } )
  names(tout)<-c("PerLess0_Method1","PerLee0_Method2")
  list(summary=tout, data=tt)  
}  
 

########  Step 1.  Test for 1 case.
n<-12
a<-runif(n,0,1)
b<-a+runif(n,0,1)*0.1
ftest1case(a=a,b=b)   

########  Step 2   Test Code 2 for multiple cases.
N<-300
tt<-ftestManyCases(N=N,printFreq = 100) 
tt[[1]]
```

Comment: This sounds like a version of [why are these two numbers not equal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal) with the same problem at its root.

Comment: Hi Allan,  Thanks for your comments on my question.  I do believe my question is close to what your link points to.  My main concern is why I am getting the negative output. I think Ben Bolker's explanation helped a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard for me to imagine when an algorithm that consists of generating 2^n permutations and adding them up is going to be more efficient than a straightforward product of differences, but I'll take your word for it that there are some special cases where it is.

As suggested in comments, the root of your problem is the accumulation of floating-point errors when adding values of different magnitudes; see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal) for an R-specific question about floating point and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) for the generic explanation.

First, a simplified example:

```r
n <- 12
set.seed(1001)
a <- runif(a,0,1)
b <- a + 0.01
prod(a-b) ## 1e-24
```

```r
out2 <- 0
N <- 2^n
out2v <- numeric(N)
for ( i in 1:N ) {
    tidx <- rev(as.integer(intToBits(x=i-1))[1:n])
    tsign <- ifelse( (sum(tidx)%%2)==0,1.0,-1.0)
    j <- as.logical(tidx)
    out2v[i] <- tsign*prod(b[!j])*prod(a[j])
}
sum(out2v)  ## -2.011703e-21
```

Using extended precision (with 1000 bits of precision) to check that the simple/brute force calculation is more reliable:

```r
library(Rmpfr)
a_m <- mpfr(a, 1000)
b_m <- mpfr(b, 1000)
prod(a_m-b_m) 
##  1.00000000000000857647286522936696473705868726043995807429578968484409120647055193862325070279593735821154440625984047036486664599510856317884962563644275433171621778761377125514191564456600405460403870124263023336542598111475858881830547350667868450934867675523340703947491662460873009229537576817962228e-24
```

This proves the point in this case, but in general doing extended-precision arithmetic will probably kill any performance gains you would get.

Redoing the permutation-based calculation with `mpfr` values (using `out2 <- mpfr(0, 1000)`, and going back to the `out2 <- out2 + ...` running summation rather than accumulating the values in a vector and calling `sum()`) gives an accurate answer (at least to the first 20 or so digits, I didn't check farther), but takes 6.5 seconds on my machine (instead of 0.03 seconds when using regular floating-point).

Why is this calculation problematic? First, note the difference between `.Machine$double.xmin` (approx 2e-308), which is the smallest floating-point value that the system can *store*, and `.Machine$double.eps` (approx 2e-16), which is the smallest value **such that 1+x > x**, i.e. the smallest *relative* value that can be added without catastrophic cancellation (values a little bit bigger than this magnitude will experience severe, but not catastrophic, cancellation).

Now look at the distribution of values in `out2v`, the series of values in `out2v`:

```r
hist(out2v)
```

[image]

There are clusters of negative and positive numbers of similar magnitude. If our summation happens to add a bunch of values that almost cancel (so that the result is very close to 0), then add that to another value that is *not* nearly zero, we'll get bad cancellation.

It's entirely possible that there's a way to rearrange this calculation so that bad cancellation doesn't happen, but I couldn't think of one easily.

Comment: Thanks a lot!  I think the parameter ".Machine$double.eps (approx 2e-16)" explains what I observed in my calculation. Every time I observed the wrong negative numbers, the output is below 2e-16. In other words, with this setting addition/subtraction in the smaller than 2e-16 is not reliable. And for these occasions, the expected positive outcome could become negative because of this".Machine$double.eps (approx 2e-16)"

Comment: One more question:  If I am only doing the summation, there seems to be no problem. In other words if I am adding very small positive numbers, the output is correct.  The negative output is produced only when I have both summation and subtraction. Maybe  it is the subtraction that causes the "cancellation", right?

Comment: the background of my calculation is to calculate the Bayesian posterior probability.   I have about 600 diseases and 4000 symptoms.  I could aggregated the probability over the diseases and I could aggregate the probability over the symptoms.  Either way I need to go through exponential times of aggregation. The formula I used that involved subtraction is when I aggregate the probability of the symptom spaces where the number of positive symptoms may be much smaller than the number of diseases.

Comment: Without more detail I'm not quite sure where the subtraction would come from.  This question is sort of on the borderline between Stack Overflow and [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com); it's possible that if you posted a detailed description of your posterior probability expression  on CV, someone would be familiar with an efficient and stable way to do the calculation (CV allows TeX markup within questions, too ...)

Comment: I have written up a deck about my problem. I can send it to you. Is your email: bolker@mcmaster.ca ?

Comment: I don't think I can do offline consultations.  Sorry ...

Comment: Hi Ben, I sent my document to your university email. No need to reply.